# CUDA compilation failed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

When I try to render with the **Cycles render** on my GPU I'll get a message which says that my **CUDA compilation failed** and I get this error in the console;

```
Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"nvcc" -arch=sm_61 --cubin "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel/kernels/cuda/kernel.cu" -o "/home/nils/.config/blender/2.78/cache/cycles_kernel_sm61_E317D1655098C1EB89BEC29AC2C7B15D.cubin" -m64 --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -DNVCC -D__KERNEL_CUDA_VERSION__=80 -I"/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/kernel" 
ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available.
       Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead.
CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.
```

Graphics card: Nvida Geforce GTX 1050ti (gigabyte=
Processor: Intel core i5 6400 (4x2.7GHz)
16gb ddr3l 1600

I have already installed gcc, g++, clang, and all Nvida drivers.

Answer (score 2):

With *buntu 20.04, modify the blender.desktop launcher to:

```
CYCLES_CUDA_EXTRA_CFLAGS="-ccbin clang-8" blender
```

As per the Blender web page as of 07-April-2020, [Blender is not compatible with gcc 4.7 or higher](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html).

The above command will launch Blender with compiler settings compatible with 20.04. The 1st GPU render requires a few minutes to compile the CUDA renderer, but afterwards renders will run immediately. Nvidia 1080 CUDA rendering was 6× faster than my old 4771 CPU alone.

Comment: For me on Debian Bullseye I needed `clang-6.0` but otherwise perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having exactly the same issue. After seeing the error message, and the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792279/set-default-host-compiler-for-nvcc), [here](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/7f4ij2/help_getting_gpu_rendering_to_work_in_linux_f27/), I think the problem was caused by nvcc not supporting the newer compiler versions installed on Debian by default. For me, the problem was solved by using the [Blender 2.79](https://www.blender.org/download/) release candidate instead. I think it may also be solved by installing older versions of the compiler.

Comment: I solved the problem: just delete this file /usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h         or just red this https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: @Revilum please post your solution as an own answer and mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

@TheCommuter is right. In addition, `clang-8` might need to be installed. This is the noob-proof guide:

1. Stop blender if it is running
2. Locate your .desktop file. try:

   `/usr/share/applications/blender.desktop`
3. open a terminal and move the file temporarily:

   `sudo mv /usr/share/applications/blender.desktop ~`
4. Edit the desktop file.

   `sudo gedit ~/blender.desktop`

   Change te Exec line to:

   `Exec=env CYCLES_CUDA_EXTRA_CFLAGS="-ccbin clang-8" blender %f`
5. Make sure clang-8 is installed:

   `sudo apt install -y clang-8`
6. Install your modified .desktop file

   `sudo desktop-file-install ~/blender.desktop`

Blender should now be available in your Applications, and work with Cycles (GPU)